# Route attributes not registering my controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to register a new route that handles login functionality the same way as I did for my other routes. The other routes worked but only the login one does not.

Here is the route attribute for **working routes**:

```
 // POST api/user/adduser
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("api/user/adduser")]
 public IHttpActionResult AddUser([FromBody]User user) 
 {
     blah blah
 }
```

Here is my code for Login method:

```
 // POST api/user/login
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("api/user/login")]
 public IHttpActionResult Login(String email, String password)
 {
     blah blah
 }
```

And finally here is my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
 // Web API routes
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "UserRouteApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/user/{method}"
 );
```

This is what the http response is when i try to access the login api ->

Output on browser:

[image]

I don't get it, I created the route the same way as I did previously. 
Tried restarting visual studio, iis express, pretty sure my route template is correct.

I need desperate help here!

Comment: I think the "Output on browser" explains it. You are doing an HTTP GET from your browser to test with, and your action method only accepts HTTP POST. Therefore, it doesn't match the request.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Yes you are right. But i am not sure, because my working route which was a  [HttpPost] gave me a different output however. Take a look (http://imgur.com/Q6X0WX8)

Comment: As NightOwl888 says, you need to make a post, however are you also adding email and password to the querystring?

'http://localhost:1538/api/user/login?email=me%40company.com&password=mypassword'

Note you will also need to encode the @ character in a querystring.

Comment: Again, you're trying to GET a resource that is only available via POST. Having email address and password as querystring parameters is probably not a good idea, I'd suggest a SignInModel with EmailAddress and Password properties and POST a JSON instance of this in the body.